# why value of ModelMap attribute getting changed in jsp?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller, modelattribute

i have a controller given below:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
AdminDaoInterface adminDao; 

@Autowired
UserValidator userValidator;

@RequestMapping(value="userdetails.htm",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String userDetails(ModelMap model) {
  UserCommand userDetailsCmd = new UserCommand();
  model.addAttribute("userDetailsCmd", userDetailsCmd);
  return "UserDetails";  // will go to UserDetails.jsp
}


@RequestMapping(value="userdetails.htm",method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public String userDetailsSubmit(
                      @ModelAttribute("userDetailsCmd") UserCommand userDetailsCmd,
                      Errors errors, ModelMap model){

  //user will contains details of user found from database.
  User user=adminDao.getUserOnId(userDetailsCmd.getUserId());

  if(user==null) {  
    errors.rejectValue("userId", "user.not.exists");
    return "UserDetails";
  }

  model.addAttribute("user",user);
  return "ChangeUserDetails"; // will go to ChangeUserDetails.jsp
}


@RequestMapping(value="changeuserdetails.htm",method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public String changeUserDetails(
             @ModelAttribute("userDetailsCmd") UserCommand userDetailsCmd,
             @ModelAttribute("user") User user){

  // some stuff...

  // BOTH user and userDetailsCmd OBJECTS HAVE A FIELD "userType"
  // HERE  user.userType SHOULD CONTAIN VALUE COLLECTED FROM DB (already
      // existing value)

  // AND userDetailsCmd.userType SHOULD CONTAIN VALUE SELECTED IN JSP IN 
  //ORDER TO UPDATE EXISTING VALUE of user.userType.                
  ...

  //BUT WHEN I SET VALUE OF userDetailsCmd.userType IN JSP, WHY VALUE OF 
  // user.userType GOT CHANGED ALWAYS TO THAT VALUE???
  ...

  // somewhere later in code i m setting user.userType to
  //userDetailsCmd.userType to update value.

  adminDao.updateUser(user);
  return "ChangeUserSuccess"; 
}

 }
```

ChangeUserDetails.jsp is:

```
<form:form method="post" action="changeuserdetails.htm" commandName="userDetailsCmd"> 

<table>

<tr>
    <td>User Id :</td>
    <td>${user.userId}</td>

</tr>


<tr>
    <td>Project :</td>
    <td>${user.projectId} </td>
    <td>Change To:</td>
    <td>
    <form:select path="projectId"> 
    <form:option value="-1" label="SELECT"/>
    <form:options items="${projectList}" itemValue="pid"        
                 itemLabel="projectName"/>
    </form:select>
    </td>   
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td>User Type :</td>
    <td>${user.userType}</td>
    <td>Change To:</td>
    <td>
    <form:select path="userType">
        <form:option value="not changed" label="SELECT"/>
        <form:option  value="admin" label="Admin" />
        <form:option value="user" label="User" />
    </form:select>
    </td>   
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Change User Details"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table> 

</form:form>
```

why value of **user.userType** always got changed when i set/change value of command object **userDetailsCmd** (*userDetailsCmd.userType*) in jsp?
is this because both have same attribute name (userType)?

**EDIT:**
UserCommand class (command object)is :

```
public class UserCommand{

private String userId;
private String password;
private int projectId;
private String userType;
private int listUserId;
private List usersList;

//PLUS getters and setters for these fields...
}
```

And User class (a POJO )is:

```
public class User{

private String userId;
private String password;
private int projectId;
private String userType;

//PLUS getters and setters for these fields...

   }
```

Comment: I really tryed, but I did not understand what you mean. What is the expected behavior and what is the behavior you observed?

Comment: @Ralph: In ChangeUserDetails.jsp, when i select some value for field **userType**, ideally (according to me) the value of command object **userDetailsCmd** should get changed only(as  `userDetailsCmd.userType`). But the problem is that upon selecting a value from `<form:select path="userType">` it is also changing the value of **user.userType**. i was expecting that it would change only `userDetailsCmd.userType` not `user.userType` as user in jsp is not the command object. `user.userType` should contain its value what it has before entering into this jsp.

Comment: Well, don't make the user a model attribute, then. Remove it from the arguments of the changeUserDetails method.

Comment: (+1) interessting question: -- We need some more details: 1) please post the `UserCommand`. 2) have you ever taken a look on the submitted http values? 3) how is the user object in the `changeUserDetails` method populated, I do not see any `user` attributes in the JSP

Comment: @Ralph: In changeUserDetails.jsp u can see **user** object as `${user.userType}`. **User** class represents a table **user** in DB...a mapping file( i m using Hibernate). Before entering into the changeUserDetails.jsp **user object** gets populated from db in `userDetailsSubmit()` method [POST request] of UserController. Then i m printing these field values of user object in changeUserDetails.jsp as `${user.userType}`. But i m not altering them. i m altering only userDetailsCmd obj (UserCommand class) in jsp . Please note that both User and UserCommand class have same field names.

Comment: @brightness: I mean how the user is getting in to METHOD `changeUserDetails`? (second method parameter)

Answer (score 0):

```
@InitBinder("user")
public void userBinding(DataBinder binder) {
    binder.setDisallowedFields("userType");
}
```

Add this to your controller and the `userType` field of the `User` object will not get populated.